# AngularJS & LoDash: Combining API objects

Tags: angularjs, lodash

--UPDATE--
Updated Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/QX00S7gH2OwmobiNUqyL?p=preview

If I uncomment the call to LoDash, everything still breaks but at least the loop works.

All code below has been updated accordingly
--UPDATE--

I have an API that is giving me data in "chunks" so I am trying to create a useable object using the incredible LoDash. My first application of LoDash works like a charm to extract one loan from several. However, when I try to add to that object, it stops working.

I have created a plunker that shows the final output that I need (in the $scope.desired variable) and the code that I have so far -- http://plnkr.co/edit/QX00S7gH2OwmobiNUqyL?p=preview

Here is my controller:

```
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.constant('_', window._)
  .run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope._ = window._;
  });

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '_', function($scope, _) {
  $scope.loans = [
    {id: 1, selCropsId: ['1','3'], budget: 30000},
    {id: 2, selCropsId: ['1','2'], budget: 50000},
    {id: 3, selCropsId: ['2','3'], budget: 10000}
  ];

  $scope.crops = [
    {id: 1, crop: 'Cotton', uom: 'lb'},
    {id: 2, crop: 'Soybeans', uom: 'bu'},
    {id: 3, crop: 'Sugar Cane', uom: 'ton'}
  ];

  $scope.funduse = [
    {loan_id: 1, crop_id: 1, seed: 150},
    {loan_id: 1, crop_id: 1, fertilizer: 85},
    {loan_id: 1, crop_id: 3, seed: 300},
    {loan_id: 1, crop_id: 3, fertilizer: 175},
    {loan_id: 2, crop_id: 1, seed: 350},
    {loan_id: 2, crop_id: 1, fertilizer: 200},
    {loan_id: 2, crop_id: 2, seed: 500},
    {loan_id: 2, crop_id: 2, fertilizer: 250},
    {loan_id: 3, crop_id: 2, seed: 80},
    {loan_id: 3, crop_id: 2, fertilizer: 20},
    {loan_id: 3, crop_id: 3, seed: 125},
    {loan_id: 3, crop_id: 3, fertilizer: 60}
  ];

  $scope.loan = _.find($scope.loans, function(i) {
      return i.id == 2;
  });

  $scope.loan.crops = [];

  for(var c=0; c<$scope.loan.selCropsId.length; c++){
    $scope.loan.crops.push($scope.loan.selCropsId[c]);
    //$scope.loan.crops.push(getUse($scope.loan.selCropsId[c]));
  }

  function getUse(id){
    _.find($scope.crops, function(i){
      return i.id == selCropsId[c];
    });
  }

  $scope.desired = [
    {
      id: 2,
      selCropsId: ['1','2'],
      budget: 50000,
      crops: [
        {
          id: 1,
          crop: 'cotton',
          uom: 'lb',
          funduse: {
            seed: 350,
            fertilizer: 200
          }
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          crop: 'Soybeans',
          uom: 'bu',
          funduse: {
            seed: 500,
            fertilizer: 250
          }
        }
      ]
    }  
  ];

}]);
```

My HTML is trivial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-rc.1" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@*" data-semver="2.4.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <pre>{{ loan | json }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ desired | json }}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with angularjs, right? It's just that you want to convert objects from one structure, to another structure -- in this case you can use lodash and it will definitely help.

Comment: I am taking an API created with Laravel and consuming it in an AngularJS frontend. I have LoDash injected into the controller. If there is a better -- an Angular way to do this -- I am willing to learn; otherwise, just figuring out why LoDash won't work the second time like it does the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 bugs in your `getUse` function.

- The first one is that you are trying to use `selCropsId[c]` when you should be using the `id` parameter.
- The second problem is that you aren't returning the result of the `_.find` call

here is your updated `getUse` function

```
  function getUse(id){
    // you need to return the result
    return _.find($scope.crops, function(i){
      return i.id == id; // you need to use the id parameter
    });
  }
```

I think that you should be able to figure out how to get the rest of the object structure that you need.